# ASM simple keylogger without use INT

Tags: assembly, input, x86, keylogger

I am coding a keylogger in C and x86 assembly. My code works fine but when user press a key the key remains pressed without stop. Here is my code in x86 asm:

```
LEA BX,[Keystroke]
Begin:
IN AL,0x64
CMP AL,0x14
JNZ Begin
IN AL,0x60
MOV [BX],AL
...
```

What is wrong at the code above? Is the `cmp al,0x14`?

Answer (score 2):

In the register 64h bit 0 indicates that data is present:

```
IN AL,0x64
TEST AL,1
JZ Begin
```

However this will not work if there is a handler for hardware interrupt #1 (keyboard).

You'll have to disable hardware interrupt #1 (interrupt "int 9") to poll the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

i want to know more about keyboard controller registers. know that bit 0 is data from keyb encdr presente is NOT enough to know waht is teh value at register 0x64. I also know that bit 5 is mouse data and it must be 0 so:

```
IN AL,0x64
TEST AL,0x20
JNZ Begin
```

Now I want to know more about register 0x64 and 0x61.

Comment: You can edit your question. You can even answer your own question and accept it *if* it's the best answer. But don't extend the question *in an answer* - and don't change the question to something else entirely.